# How to save checkbox value to database Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

here's my form code :

```
 <div class="form-group">
          <label>Warranty:</label>
          {{ Form::checkbox('warranty', 0, false) }}
 </div>
```

here's my controller code :

```
public function save(Request $request, $obj = null) {

if (!$obj) {
    $obj = new Service;
}
(Input::has('warranty')) ? true : false;
return $this->saveHandler($request, $obj);
}
```

it throws this error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found

any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `request` object to get the `warranty` input as:

```
$request->get('warranty')
```

or

```
$request->has('warranty')
```

Comment: it throws syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN).

Answer (score 3):

```
 $request->merge(array('checkbox_name' => $request->has('checkbox_name') ? true : false));
Object::create($request->all());
```

This is how I save boolean parameters which are checkboxes in form.

Or simply give your checkbox value

```
 {{ Form::checkbox('checkbox_name', 1) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Input` facade was removed in latest verison, so you can add it to `config/app.php`:

```
'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
```

Or add this line to the beginning of a controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

Or write full path when you use it:

```
(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::has('warranty')) ? true : false;
```

Comment: it throws Class 'Input' not found

Comment: As far as I know, it was removed time ago:


`"The Input facade, which was primarily a duplicate of the Request facade, has been removed. If you are using the Input::get method, you should now call the Request::input method. All other calls to the Input facade may simply be updated to use the Request facade."`



From 6.x documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#the-input-facade

Comment: Forgot in previous comment: You need to use `$request->input('input_name')` instead of Input Facade.

Answer (score 1):

Add this at top in the controller,

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

Comment: it throws Class 'Input' not found.

Comment: Do you have Input Class in controllers?

Comment: 'App\Http\Controllers\Input ' says you have Input class in controllers which cannot be found. If you want to use Input Facade you have to remove 'App\Http\Controllers\Input ' and replace it with Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;